# How to handle Many-To-Many In Grails without belongsTo?

Tags: grails, many-to-many

I need to create a many-to-many relationship in Grails.

I have a "Question" domain and a "Tag" domain. 
A Question can have 0 or more tags. A Tag can have 0 or more Questions.

If I put a "hasMany" on each sides, it gives me an error saying I need a "belongTo" somewhere. 
However, adding a belongsTo means that the owner must exist...

Like I said, a Tag could have 0 questions, and a Question could have 0 tags. 
There is no concept of an owner, it's a many-to-many!

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 6):

you can do this (please see the code below). but does it make sense to have a question tag with out both a question and a tag?

```
    package m2msansbt

    class Question {
        String toString() { return name }
        String name
        static hasMany=[questionTags:QuestionTag]
        static constraints = {
        }
    }
    package m2msansbt

    class Tag {
        String toString() { return name }
        String name
        static hasMany=[questionTags:QuestionTag]
        static constraints = {
        }
    }
package m2msansbt

class QuestionTag {
    Question question
    Tag tag
    static QuestionTag link(Question question,Tag tag) {
        QuestionTag questionTag=QuestionTag.findByQuestionAndTag(question,tag)
        if (!questionTag) {
            questionTag = new QuestionTag()
            question?.addToQuestionTags(questionTag)
            tag?.addToQuestionTags(questionTag)
            questionTag.save() 

        }
        return questionTag
    }
    static void unlink(Question question,Tag tag) {
        QuestionTag questionTag=QuestionTag.findByQuestionAndTag(question,tag)
        if (questionTag) {
            question?.removeFromQuestionTags(questionTag)
            tag?.removeFromQuestionTags(questionTag)
            questionTag.delete()
        }
    }
    static constraints = {
    }
}

 import m2msansbt.*
 class BootStrap {

         def init = { servletContext ->
            Question q1=new Question(name:'q1')
            Tag t1=new Tag(name:'t1')
            Tag t2=new Tag(name:'t2')
            q1.save()
            t1.save()
            t2.save()
            QuestionTag q1t1=QuestionTag.link(q1,t1)
            q1t1.save()
            QuestionTag q1t2=QuestionTag.link(q1,t2)
            q1t2.save()
            q1.save()
            t1.save()
         }
         def destroy = {
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If your main concern is the cascading delete, you can take a look at [5.5.2.9](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#5.5.2%20Custom%20ORM%20Mapping) in the grails docs to manually disable it for the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but I think the [`mappedBy`](http://grails.org/doc/1.2.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html) property can be used to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [Taggable Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/taggable).

It seems to solve the problem you are having and you could look at the [source code](http://fisheye.codehaus.org/browse/grails-plugins/grails-taggable) if you want to see how they modeled the relationship. BTW this plugin was originally created by Graeme Rocher who is the lead developer on Grails.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Grails 2.4.4. Add a "belongsTo" with just the classname.

```
class Question {
    String toString() { return name }
    String name
    static hasMany=[tags:Tag]
    static constraints = {
    }
}


class Tag {
    String toString() { return name }
    String name
    static hasMany=[questions:Question]

    static belongsTo = Question

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```