# Grails many to many relationship without belongsTo

Tags: database, grails

I have 3 domains A,B,C .A has Many B and B has Many A (Many to many relationship between A and B ), and A and B **belongs to C** domain.
Now my problems is how can i manage Many to many relationship between A and B,because without one parent its grails throw error parent must required.
In my case C is parent of A and B.so now how can i manage many to many relationship between A and B where both belong to C ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have already mentioned Grails will not allow creation on the many to many without belongTo in one of the domain so there is no way to do it in Grails.

In many to many relationship a separate table is created automatically by the name A_B so this relationship can be managed by created your own domain AB which belongsTo A and B both are nullable: true and now you will A hasMany AB and B hasMany AB.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by mapping the relationship class explicitly [as in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775332/how-to-handle-many-to-many-in-grails-without-belongsto)